# Is it possible to change the colour of vertex indicators in Blender?

Tags: interface, vertices, customization, theme

I have to select some vertices that are very close together with ones I do not wish to select and its quite hard to see them. I was wondering if the little black dots (which indicates a vertex) can be changed to luminous orange or blue or whatever colour other than black.

I'm hoping it is possible , but googling didn't really link me to stuff related to what I want.

(nb. I hope this makes sense and I've used the correct terms, Im still very new to modelling. If you don't know exactly what I mean I could probably paste some screenshots to illustrate it.)

Comment: Don't [themes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61627/vertex-dots-in-edit-mode-disappeared-how-to-get-them-back) do what you need?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I will take a look into Themes to see if this will help me. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to *File* -> *User Preferences* then in the Themes tab select *"3D View"* on the left side and change the color of *"Vertex"*.

[image: Theme Settings]